# How to draw non-scalable text in SVG with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3 library to create a svg graphic. The problem I have is when I resize the window. The whole graphic resizes meaning that texts (legend and axis) resize as well, to the point where it's unreadable. I need it to keep the same size when resizing.

I've been searching online and I found this solution:

```
var resizeTracker;
            // Counteracts all transforms applied above an element.
            // Apply a translation to the element to have it remain at a local position
            var unscale = function (el) {        

                var svg = el.ownerSVGElement;
                var xf = el.scaleIndependentXForm; 

                if (!xf) {
                    // Keep a single transform matrix in the stack for fighting transformations
                    xf = el.scaleIndependentXForm = svg.createSVGTransform();
                    // Be sure to apply this transform after existing transforms (translate)
                    el.transform.baseVal.appendItem(xf);
                }
                var m = svg.getTransformToElement(el.parentNode);
                m.e = m.f = 0; // Ignore (preserve) any translations done up to this point
                xf.setMatrix(m);                    
            };
            [].forEach.call($("text"), unscale);
            $(window).resize(function () {                                  
                if (resizeTracker) clearTimeout(resizeTracker);
                resizeTracker = setTimeout(function () { [].forEach.call($("text"), unscale); }, 0);
            });
```

And added it to my code, but it's not working. I debugged it and at this part of the code:

```
var xf = el.scaleIndependentXForm;
```

It always returns the same matrix: 1 0 0 1 0 0 and the text keeps resizing as does the rest of the svg elements instead of keeping static.

Could anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to style your text on CSS, something like: .labels { font-size:10px; }

Comment: @RobertLongson no, when resizing it's always "SVGMatrix { a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, e: 0, f: 0 }"

Comment: @Klaujesi I have already added the font-size and it's always the same font-size when resizing.

Comment: So, now it's working?. That's what you need, right?

Comment: @Klaujesi no it's not, I had added that before writing this post! It's not a font-size problem I'm afraid.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without any markup to go with it. Try creating a stack snippet or a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing was happening to me with an SVG generated by SnapSVG until I noted that the [example page on which this does work](http://meloncholy.com/static/demos/responsive-svg-graph-1/) wraps its 'main' SVG tag in another SVG tag before using `el.ownerSVGElement.ownerSVGElement` rather than `el.ownerSVGElement`.

Wrapping my SVG in an 'empty' wrapper SVG (note style `overflow:visible;`) I had much better results!

Edit: oh, wait. Internet Explorer still isn't happy. [Seems the author of the solution is aware...](http://meloncholy.com/blog/making-responsive-svg-graphs/)